# Scrapy CrawlSpider doesn't scrape with callback = 'parse_page'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy's CrawlSpider to scrape product info on     https://www.walmart.com/browse/makeup/lips/1085666_1007040_1001527.
This is what my rules look like:

```
   rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="mainSearchContent"]/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]',)
        ),
                callback = 'parse_page',
                follow =True),)
```

And this is the result. It doesn't scrape anything.

```
017-07-05 13:32:33 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline
2017-07-05 13:32:33 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-05 13:32:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-05 13:32:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2017-07-05 13:32:35 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.walmart.com/browse/makeup/lips/1085666_1007040_1001527> (referer: None)
2017-07-05 13:32:35 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-05 13:32:35 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 322,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 157281,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5, 10, 32, 35, 320638),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 6,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5, 10, 32, 33, 900621)}
```

If I change callback to parse, it only scrapes the first page.
Can anyone tell me how to scrape all pages?

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve your issue. but there is an easy way to fetch data from that website. just request [their API](https://www.walmart.com/search/api/wpa?el=sponsored-container-bottom-1&type=product&min=2&max=20&creative=1145x345_B-C-OG_TI_2-20_HL-BOTTOM&placementId=1145x345_B-C-OG_TI_2-20_HL-BOTTOM&theme=large&platform=desktop&bucketId=&isSpecialBrowse=false&pageType=browse&pageId=1085666_1007040_1001527&pageNumber=1&keyword=Lips&taxonomy=1085666_1007040_1001527&vtc=bXdXxb3UiKhDx6eTotCM-E&uid=75e86169-c8ab-4178-88d8-3bd0242c5069&itemsList=24520263%2C19408713%2C26775062%2C43984097%2C52664389%2C13865594%2C189016376%2C15641929%2C27419883%2C10314309&rviItems=&itemsAddedToCart=0&viewportHeight=335&viewportWidth=1439&accessModeEnabled=true)

This should be a comment, but the URL is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'callback' should be a method name, not a string.